# jquery drop down menu positioning

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I needed to create a drop down menu which would open up instead of down.
Going through [this](http://www.instantshift.com/2010/07/16/create-simple-dropdown-menu-using-jquery/), I figured how to create a drop down and then modified it according to my requirement, finally resulting in [this (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/QqEKw/3/).

I now wanted to make this drop down stick to the bottom of the page, so I changed the css of the container to `position:absolute;bottom:0;`. However, my drop down does not display correctly anymore, as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QqEKw/4/).

Can anyone please explain why this is happening and how to go about doing it correctly?

Thanks in advance. :)

EDIT:

Thanks to kei and bukfixart, I now used both the codes given below alternately with the same result: they work in IE9, but do not work (read: behave strangely) in Chrome or Firefox. You can see the bizarre behaviour [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZC4sz/2/).
Note that this happens only when all 4 tabs are in the same line.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening??

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/ZC4sz/)

In your jQuery, change it from

```
    submenu.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: $(this).offset().top - submenu.height() + 'px',
        left: $(this).offset().left + 'px',
        zIndex: 1000
    });
```

to

```
    submenu.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: $("#container").height() + 'px',
        left: $(this).offset().left + 'px',
        zIndex: 1000
    });
```

Comment: @Fahad That's more of a CSS issue. Just add `#container { width:100%; }` [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZC4sz/3/)

Comment: Thanks alot :) if its not too much trouble, can you please explain the issue so I don't make the same mistake in future? I did not really understand it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple reason for this.

You should replace your code with this

```
    submenu.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top:  - submenu.height() + 'px',
        left: $(this).offset().left + 'px',
        zIndex: 1000
    });
```

(removed the height of the parent).
You gave the parent a absolute positioning. So the childs are oriented at the parents position. In this case the height isn't neccessary in the calculation

Just give the `#container` element always a `relative` or `absolute` position, and you can use the fixed script in all cases

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the solution. One problem though, now. If you open http://jsfiddle.net/ZC4sz/2 (fiddle with your  suggestion) and expand the result window enough such that all 4 tabs are visible at once, and now hover upon the div, the layout breaks, and Tab 4 comes below the first tab. This happens only in Chrome though, works okay in IE9.